# Entity Framework not accepting clustered index attribute

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a class in my EF model:

```
public class Comment
        {
        public string CommentId { get; set;}
        public string TextMarkdown { get; set;}
        public string TextHtml { get { return new Markdown().Transform(TextMarkdown); } }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
        public int BlogId { get; set;}
        public virtual Blog BlogOwner { get; set; }
        }
```

I changed my class to this:

```
public class Comment
        {
        public int CommentId { get; set;}
        public string TextMarkdown { get; set;}
        public string TextHtml { get { return new Markdown().Transform(TextMarkdown); } }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
        public int BlogId { get; set;}
        public virtual Blog BlogOwner { get; set; }
        }
```

I'm using Code First migrations. I issued these commands:

> add-migration "Changed CommentId to int"
>
> update-database

The update database command fails with an error

> Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of
>   SQL Server. Please create a clustered index and try again.

So I added an Index attribute on my CommentId property. I removed the last migration, issued the add migration and update database commands again.

```
public class Comment
        {
        [Index(IsClustered = true)]
        public int CommentId { get; set;}
        //rest of class omitted for brevity
        }
```

But I get the same error. What am I doing wrong? Here's my migration code:

```
public override void Up()
        {
            DropPrimaryKey("dbo.Comments");
            AlterColumn("dbo.Comments", "CommentId", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
            AddPrimaryKey("dbo.Comments", "CommentId");
            CreateIndex("dbo.Comments", "CommentId", clustered: true);
        }
```

Background: I'm using EF 6.1.1 and a SQL Server database hosted in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

You need a clustered index on the Comment_Blog relationship.  In azure, ALL tables must have clustered indexes (you technically can have them, but not for normal usage). One way to confirm/detect this is by deploying to a local SQL database.  Then you can run the script mentioned here: [list of tables without indexes in sql 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1371448/1070412) to find the tables that don't have indexes.

Comment: And how do I do that from EF and migrations? I've tried `CreateIndex("dbo.Comments", new []{"BlogId", "CommentId"}, clustered: true);` in my Up() method but got the same error.

Comment: It's possible there's a different relationship causing this. If you deploy to a local instance and then run that script it should be obvious which relationship is the issue and from there I can help with the proper index creation if it's not apparent.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up migrating to a version of the database just before I created the Comments table. Then I created a new migration so that when the table is created the CommentId would be an int instead of a string.

I guess something about the order of doing things was causing issues. Good thing I didn't have live data in my database or I would have lost it.