# Automation of SQL Server Migration with selective table truncation

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, database-migration

Just wondering if any SQL Server experts out there have any tips that can help in my testing of a MS-Access port to SQL Server using the Migration Assistant and with selective Drop+Create SQL scripting.

I have a new SQL Server database that I'm migrating from a total of 5 external MS-Access databases. The one database gets changed daily and I'd like to update my test SQL Server with new data every once in awhile

My problem right now is that I don't want to Drop + Create the whole database.
I'd just like to selectively drop the tables being migrated in from the one MS-Access database.

I can't see an option for that inside SQL Server. Is there a tool or menu item that I missing?

I'm using SQL Server 13.0 (2017) and I have SQL Server 2016 Import/Export Wizard

Comment: I highly recommend not using an import/export wizard, but using a custom VBA/SQL script to migrate the databases. That way, you do have this control. Depending on your situation, you can trigger this from SQL server using a stored procedure and `SELECT .. INTO .. FROM OPENROWSET(Access database)` or from the Access database using VBA.

Comment: This looks promising - wasn't aware of OpenRowset - it looks like an offshoot of the old bcp command line tool. So I could take a dump of the SQL for all tables, remove ones not needed. But setting up custom field mappings might tedious? I guess it's still a one time setup that can be reused.

Comment: It's just SQL. You can map fields by aliasing them, and use typecasting functions if the fields need casting. Since SQL is very familiar to me, I prefer it over the GUI tools. You can even use complex operations, such as `UNPIVOT`, if your dataset needs normalization. For advanced users, you can get into dynamic SQL using MSysObjects and stored procedures to auto-handle imports.

Comment: Ok. I can start to visualize this now. It does seem like a daunting first setup though, or is it possible to use a dump from a SQL Export task to start with? It could show all the field names from each table?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the modern export tools (every time I tried to use one, I ended up doing it all in VBA if the database wasn't on the server, or all in SQL if it was). I don't believe you can do this, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm missing something.

Create a SQL script, that you run before running the import.

```
-- Drop all tables imported from Access database x
DROP TABLE foo;
DROP TABLE bar;
-- etc
GO
```

To avoid typing all the table names, see e.g. [list of tables without indexes in sql 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369551/list-of-tables-without-indexes-in-sql-2008)

Or use `MSysObjects` in the source database.